# Multi Condition Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have a problem which is related to query performance.

First
when I am trying to run this query on oracle table that contains over 13 million records

```
Select * 
from Table1 
where CATSEARCH(NAME,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0
```

the above query taking 0.002 seconds to get 36000 rows

also

```
Select * 
from Table1 
where ID = 123  //less than one second - one row result
```

But when I am trying to add multi filter using AND such as the below statement

```
Select * 
from Table1 
where CATSEARCH(NAME,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0 
  AND ID = 123
```

This took more than 10 seconds to retrieve the result of one row.

Second
the same problem when using OR

```
Select * 
from Table1 
where CATSEARCH(NAME,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0 
   OR ID = 123 //10 to 14 seconds
```

Table Structure

```
  CREATE TABLE "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" 
   (    "OBJECTID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAB_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FAC_SEQ" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "LAB_NAME" NVARCHAR2(40), 
    "FAC_NAME" NVARCHAR2(60), 
    "ZAQAT_ID" NVARCHAR2(14), 
    "ACTIVITY" NVARCHAR2(180), 
    "FAC_STATUS" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "COMM_REG" NVARCHAR2(12), 
    "COMM_ISSUE_LOC" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "MUNI_LIC_ID" NVARCHAR2(12), 
    "MUNI_LIC_LOC" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "ADD_CITY" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "ADD_DISTRICT" NVARCHAR2(30), 
    "ADD_STREET" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "ADD_POBOX" NVARCHAR2(7), 
    "ADD_POST_ID" NVARCHAR2(7), 
    "ADD_TEL1" NVARCHAR2(9), 
    "ADD_TEL2" NVARCHAR2(9), 
    "ADD_FAX" NVARCHAR2(9), 
    "ADD_EMAIL" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "MANAGER_NAME" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "FAC_SCOPE" NVARCHAR2(20), 
    "FAC_SIZE" NVARCHAR2(20), 
    "FAC_ACTIVITY" NVARCHAR2(200), 
    "SADUI_NUMBERS" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FOR_NUMBERS" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FAC_ISTEQDAM_ID" NVARCHAR2(10), 
    "FAC_NATIONALITY" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "OWNER_NAME" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "OWNER_NATIONALITY" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "OWNER_ID" NVARCHAR2(15), 
    "OWNER_GENDER" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "OWNER_ADD_CITY" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "OWNER_ADD_DISTRICT" NVARCHAR2(30), 
    "OWNER_ADD_STREET" NVARCHAR2(30), 
    "OWNER_ADD_PO" NVARCHAR2(7), 
    "OWNER_ADD_POSTID" NVARCHAR2(7), 
    "OWNER_ADD_TEL1" NVARCHAR2(9), 
    "OWNER_ADD_TEL2" NVARCHAR2(9), 
    "OWNER_ADD_FAX" NVARCHAR2(15), 
    "OWNER_ADD_EMAIL" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "OWNER_MOBILE" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "IQAMA_ID" NVARCHAR2(150), 
    "FIRST_NAME" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "FATHER_NAME" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "GRAND_NAME" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "FAMILY_NAME" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "EMPLOYEE_NAT" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "EMPLOYEE_RELG" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "EMPLOYEE_PASSPORT_ID" NVARCHAR2(30), 
    "EMPLOYEE_GENDER" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "EMPLOYEE_BIRTH_YEAR" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "EMPLOYEE_OCC" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "EMPLOYEE_STATUS" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "EMPLOYEE_BORDER_NUMBE" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "NAME" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "NAME2" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "NAME3" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "ACTIVITY2" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), 
    "NAME3_2" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 4 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "GIS_SDE_DATA" ;


  CREATE INDEX "SDE"."INDX_ACTCNT2" ON "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" ("ACTIVITY2") 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CTXCAT" ;

  CREATE INDEX "SDE"."INDX_NAME3_2" ON "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" ("NAME3_2") 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CTXCAT" ;

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SDE"."R509_SDE_ROWID_UK" ON "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" ("OBJECTID") 
  PCTFREE 0 INITRANS 4 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "GIS_SDE_INDEXES" ;

  CREATE INDEX "SDE"."INDX_NAME3" ON "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" ("NAME3") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "GIS_SDE_DATA" ;

  CREATE INDEX "SDE"."INDX_ACT" ON "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" ("ACTIVITY") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "GIS_SDE_DATA" ;

  CREATE INDEX "SDE"."INDX_IQAMA_ID" ON "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" ("IQAMA_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "GIS_SDE_DATA" ;


  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SDE"."DR$INDX_ACTCNT2TC" after insert or update on "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" for each row declare   reindex boolean := FALSE;   updop   boolean := FALSE; begin   ctxsys.drvdml.c_updtab.delete;   ctxsys.drvdml.c_numtab.delete;   ctxsys.drvdml.c_vctab.delete;   ctxsys.drvdml.c_rowid := :new.rowid;   if (inserting or updating('ACTIVITY2') or       :new."ACTIVITY2" <> :old."ACTIVITY2") then     reindex := TRUE;     updop := (not inserting);     ctxsys.drvdml.c_text_vc2 := :new."ACTIVITY2";   end if;   ctxsys.drvdml.ctxcat_dml('SDE','INDX_ACTCNT2', reindex, updop); end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "SDE"."DR$INDX_ACTCNT2TC" ENABLE;
BEGIN 
  DBMS_DDL.SET_TRIGGER_FIRING_PROPERTY('"SDE"','"DR$INDX_ACTCNT2TC"',FALSE) ; 
END;
/


  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SDE"."DR$INDX_NAME3_2TC" after insert or update on "SDE"."LABOUR_OFFICE" for each row declare   reindex boolean := FALSE;   updop   boolean := FALSE; begin   ctxsys.drvdml.c_updtab.delete;   ctxsys.drvdml.c_numtab.delete;   ctxsys.drvdml.c_vctab.delete;   ctxsys.drvdml.c_rowid := :new.rowid;   if (inserting or updating('NAME3_2') or       :new."NAME3_2" <> :old."NAME3_2") then     reindex := TRUE;     updop := (not inserting);     ctxsys.drvdml.c_text_vc2 := :new."NAME3_2";   end if;   ctxsys.drvdml.ctxcat_dml('SDE','INDX_NAME3_2', reindex, updop); end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "SDE"."DR$INDX_NAME3_2TC" ENABLE;
BEGIN 
  DBMS_DDL.SET_TRIGGER_FIRING_PROPERTY('"SDE"','"DR$INDX_NAME3_2TC"',FALSE) ; 
END;
/
```

Execuation Plan FOR
    Select * 
    from Table1 
    where CATSEARCH(NAME,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0 
      AND ID = 123

```
Plan hash value: 2958045980 
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name              |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                   |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | LABOUR_OFFICE     |
|   2 |   BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS    |                   |
|   3 |    BITMAP AND                    |                   |
|   4 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|                   |
|   5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | R509_SDE_ROWID_UK |
|   6 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|                   |
|   7 |      SORT ORDER BY               |                   |
|   8 |       DOMAIN INDEX               | INDX_NAME3_2      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What are the execution plans for each of the queries?

Comment: Also, please post the table structure, including indexes

Comment: How much this query takes ? `Select count(*)
from Table1 
where CATSEARCH(NAME,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0`

Comment: What is a *very problem*?

Comment: @mathguy Sorry wrong word

Comment: @GauravSoni +9 seconds !!! with 700,000 row count

Comment: @Aleksej I have updated the main question with the table structure 

The actual query:
Select * 
from LABOUR_OFFICE
where CATSEARCH(NAME3_2,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0 
  AND OBJECTID = 123

Comment: @Aleksej I just updated the main question body with the execution plan

Comment: @Boneist I just updated the main question body with the execution plan

Comment: Not that I have much hopes, but could you try the combined select swapping the order of the conditions (i.e. `where ID = 123 AND CATSEARCH(NAME,'%ABCD% | %DCBA%', null) > 0`)?

Comment: @AshrafELHakim You asked why the query return 36000 records  in 0.002 seconds and why it takes time for other,one thing i assume that if your using sql developer or toad ,it shows only the top rows within few milli seconds and when you drag down to see the data further ,it again takes time.Thats why i asked you to look into the count ,because the aggregate do operation on all the records not only the top one.But your query is returning more that 36000 ,its 700,000 records when we count it